# How can I convert $r = 2\cos{\theta}+2\sqrt{3}\sin{\theta}$ to cartesian coordinates?

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates

I'm struggling to figure out this circle equation in polar coordinates:

$r = 2\cos{\theta}+2\sqrt{3}\sin{\theta}$

and converting it to cartesian form.

How can I convert this to cartesian? How can I tell its radius and center point in both polar and cartesian forms?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply
$x = r\cos(\theta),
y=r\sin(\theta)
$
and
$r^2 = x^2+y^2$.

$r 
= 2\cos(\theta)+2\sqrt{3}\sin(\theta)
$
and
$r^2 = x^2+y^2
$
so
$r^2 
= 2r\cos(\theta)+2\sqrt{3}r\sin(\theta)
=2x+2\sqrt{3}y
=x^2+y^2
$
so
$x^2-2x+y^2-2\sqrt{3}y
=0
$
or
$x^2-2x+1+y^2-2\sqrt{3}y+3
=4
$
or
$(x-1)^1+(y-\sqrt{3})^2
=4
$.

More generally,
if
$r 
= 2a\cos(\theta)+2b\sin(\theta)
$,
then
$r^2 
= 2ar\cos(\theta)+2br\sin(\theta)
=2ax+2by
=x^2+y^2
$,
so
$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2
=a^2+b^2
$.

This is a circle with center
$(a, b)$
and radius
$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
It passes through the origin,
$(0, 2b), (2a, 0), (2a, 2b)$.

Comment: Sorry @marty-cohen, there was a typo, the equation has a plus between right hand terms. Corrected now.

Comment: OK. Made it simpler.

Comment: Thank you so so much. Specially for making it general!

Comment: I always prefer to solve an infinite number of problems rather than just one.